# Is it possible to empty certain mysql data after few seconds?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to empty data every 10 seconds on mysql. The reason for that is a third party app will update that data cell everytime and when that data cell is empty my code knows that the third part app is not running because it didnt update it on time.

Is this possible on mysql? Thanks

Comment: yes , by events

Comment: You can use the [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html) to run a query periodically.

Comment: a watchdog function

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be done in 2 ways

Method 1: if you have `updated_on` column, then you can check it through a normal `SELECT` query and decide if third party is working or not.

Method 2: Or You can create an `EVENT` to empty(truncate) the data as follows provided you have access to EVENTS (some shared hosting providers do not allow it)

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` EVENT `emptyMyTable` ON SCHEDULE EVERY
    10 SECOND STARTS '2021-06-18 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
BEGIN

TRUNCATE `your_table_name`

END
```

But ensure that your scheduler is `ON`

```
SHOW VARIABLES
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler'
```

Comment: Method 2 is not safe. The following sequence of events is possible: ***3rd app insert - Event truncate - App check - 3rd app insert***. Method 1 is free of this problem.